# How to answer a call using gsm modem and detect key press from caller after answering a call

Tags: c#, modem, at-command

I want to write code that will answer call using gsm modem and detect key press from caller after answering a call. I can answer a call using mobile modem but for edge modem it is showing 'NO CARRIER' and caller gets busy tone. Also, I want to receive call from gsm modem and detect the pressed keys from the caller's phone. I am using C#. I just need the AT commands.

Comment: i'm just a beginner with gsm modem.. do you have any tutorial so that i can learn programming gsm modem .?

Comment: start with this...
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/38705/Send-and-Read-SMS-through-a-GSM-Modem-using-AT-Com